# How do you reference a Key from Azure Key Vault in a function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, putty, azure-keyvault, pem

I've used quite a few secrets for Azure Functions in the past, and now I am trying to use a Key, RSA encrypted , 4096 bits. It's a private PuTTy .ppk key, which I've exported to a .pem type to match Azure's requirements. I have a Python 3.7 App in which I have deployed the needed function and I have tried to reference in the Application Settings the needed key with the following statement :

@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://{thevault-address}.vault.azure.net/keys/{thekey-name}/)

as well as

@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://{thevault-address}.vault.azure.net/keys/{thekey-name}/latestVersionHash)

But when I try to save it , it says that the reference could not be resolved.

The application has Identity On and the Vault has access policies for the Function configured for secrets as Get and List and for Keys as everything (initially just Get and List but added the rest just in case, because I thought that it might be an 'encription/decription' issue).

And idea why am I getting the Status:InvalidSyntax and Error Details:
Key Vault reference was not able to be resolved because invalid Key Vault reference syntax found ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you described above is perfectly correct to reference a Secret.That is why in the string `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=` you set **SecretUri** equals to...

**For Keys thow, that would not be possible**. A Key cannot be referenced by an azure web app.

---

To clear any confusion in order to reference a secret to Azure KeyVault from a web app you need three points

1. You application identity On
2. Set policies in in Keyvault so your app would be able to access the value
3. In your web app, in Configuration tab you set the value of your variable as `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={Secret Identifier})`.

Secret identifier can be found if you go to your Keyvault resource and click your secret

[image]

The identity value needs to be identical.

Comment: Sadly, no, I tried that already. The / at the end if you don't specify the version is to signal that the reference is for the latest version of the secret/key. I have secrets referenced like this , that work perfectly : @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://thevault-address.vault.azure.net/secrets/thesecret-name/) . Oh and for the SecretUri={...}, the curly bracket are not needed. In any case I tried all the variants, with braces, without, with /, without /, but it's just not working for keys. Secrets is perfectly fine.

Comment: @VladS curly braces was there only to show tha this is a variable. It should only be the Indentifier.

Comment: @VladS I was reading documentation of KeyVault. It is not possible to reference it as you do with Secrets. You can access it through the available Apis if you wish.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah found it. It seems that I need to use a library for Python , azure.keyvault.key and azure.identity. Thank you :)

Comment: You can still issue a get call and get the key. There is an available get point to get the key. But you can not reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately App Services / Azure Functions only support referencing secrets, not keys or certificates. In fact, Key Vault won't let you access the private half of a key at all, so you'll need to store it as a secret if you need to access it, or use the Key Vault SDK if you just want to do encryption/decryption using the saved key.