# Azure Function Key Vault reference mapping for keys

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

If your Azure environment is configured correctly, you can use "[Azure Key Vault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references)" in the configuration of an Azure Function to automatically import a secret or a [certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603023/682042) as an environment variable for that Azure Function. Unfortunately, I was not able to connect a key (e.g. private key) in the same way to an Azure Function.

I used the value  ´@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/keys/TestKey/)´ as well as ´@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/TestKey/)´ to access the key, but it was unsuccessful in both cases. The first value is the one that is available as the "Key Identifier" in the properties of the key in Azure Key Vault, however there does not seem to be a "Secret Identifier" like in the Certificates area. Needless to say, both values do not map to the Azure Key Vault but just return the string I entered there.

Due to the missing "Secret identifier" link, I have the suspicion that this Feature might not be supported, however, I cannot find any confirmation. Do I have an issue in my approach or is it just an unsupported feature?

Comment: First please check that in your KeyVault configuration you authorize your azure function to read  from the keyVault. Second you can add the secret version and check however i's optional  ? @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/secrets/KeyName/KeyVersion)

Comment: @MahdiSalah The Managed Identity of the Azure Function has the required permissions (I gave the test app full permissions on everything related to keys and secrets). To verify the general connection between Key Vault and Azure Function, I also have a secret in the Key Vault, which is read correctly. Referencing a version did not change the behavior.

Comment: @lafe I believe its giving the full string because, there is no value in the key

Comment: @lafe AFAIK, its not feasible to refer the key directly like we do for secrets and certificates. Instead you can use the key vault Rest APIs or libraries to get the key https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to the missing "Secret identifier" link, I have the suspicion that this Feature might not be supported, however, I cannot find any confirmation. Do I have an issue in my approach or is it just an unsupported feature?

AFAIK, it is not feasible to fetch the Keys directly from Key Vault like we do for Secrets and Certificates using `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={Secret_identifier})`.

Instead you can use the Key Vault [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/operation-groups?view=rest-keyvault-keys-7.4#rest-operation-groups) to fetch the keys or you can use the libraries too like I am using below-

```py
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential
from  azure.keyvault.keys  import  KeyClient

credential  =  DefaultAzureCredential()  
key_client  =  KeyClient(vault_url="https://{Keyvault_name}.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)
key  =  key_client.get_key("{Key_name}")
print(key.name)
```

***Output***-

[image]

***References***-

[How do you reference a Key from Azure Key Vault in a function app? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104285/how-do-you-reference-a-key-from-azure-key-vault-in-a-function-app).

[Azure Key Vault Keys client library for Python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/).